# How do I get someone to stop liking/spamming memes?

Tags: friends

Okay, so this little "lol r4nd0m m3m35t3r XDXDXDXD" I know keeps spamming me with a bunch of useless, irritating, and non-funny "memes," to which my response is asking her to kindly not do that, and to act like she is a rational human being who isn't constantly trying to grab attention by pretending to be funny. This is a serious question I need answered and I really want to put a stop to this. The "lol random" thing she's going through is hopefully a phase and she'll maybe grow out of it, but seeing her act like this out of nowhere after 3-4 years of me knowing her, and her *not acting like this* really does annoy me. I've asked her to stop sending me these things and to kindly stop talking about it all the time (as I don't like it), but she never listens. Help? (Please note: I know there is another question like this, but none of the answers seemed to fit exactly what I needed)

Comment: Via email, FB, instagram, twitter?  What relationship is she to you?

Comment: via skype. She's a very close friend

Comment: I tried looking at the answers from that question, and none seemed to help. It's why I posted this

Comment: @htfw Why are the answers for the other question are not helpful? Expanding upon that can prevent people from voting to close as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing likely to be effective is the obvious thing. Tell her you will block her for 3 days every time she sends something stupid.  Then do it.

She'll be mad; she'll tell you that you are over-reacting.  You aren't.  You made a reasonable request, and she ran right over it. So stick to your guns.